# Encrypting and Decrypting by Certificate Not Working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I am trying to encrypt some data in SQL server using an existing key and certificate.  I know this key and certificate work as I'm able to pull information from another table in the database but for some reason my SQL below isn't working.  Am I doing something wrong?

```
declare @encryption table (
string varbinary(max)
 )

open symmetric key aaaa decryption by certificate bbbb

insert into @encryption
select  encryptbykey(key_guid('aaaa'), 'Test', 1, convert(varbinary, 
'1234'))

select  string,
    convert(nvarchar(max), decryptbykey(string, 1, convert(varbinary, 
'1234')))
from    @encryption
```

I'm just getting this from the results.

string = 0x006924CD26547347A19BCA9B53E93E4501000000B01C808AB6802A5FD2781671BF50745638EDC8A55D0DC302F6CA9E3B7AE80913A297D0E34F14F4EA87B7E88F8066C38D718CA2E3092DF8A4C364CD8955CE61B7

decrypted string = 敔瑳

Appreciate any advise / help!

Thanks

Comment: right of the bat, did you try to convert into varchar instead?

Comment: Oh balls...it was that easy.  *hangs head in shame*

Comment: :) make sure you close the key afterwards